# Python json delete all instances of key regardless of location in tree

Tags: python, json, key, element

I have some json data where I need to remove every instance of a key in my Python app.

E.g., I want to remove "badKey" wherever it occurs in the following json data.

```
{
  "badKey": "0001",
  "goodKey": "5432",
  "interestingList": [
    {
      "badKey": "0001",
      "goodKey": "0101"
    }
  ],
  "coolList": {
    "nestedDeeper": [
      {
        "keepsNesting": [
          {
            "badKey": "9999",
            "otherKey": "7890"
          }
        ],
        "hereToo": {
          "badKey": "foobar",
          "goodishKey": "baz"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It should result in the following:

```
{
  "goodKey": "5432",
  "interestingList": [
    {
      "goodKey": "0101"
    }
  ],
  "coolList": {
    "nestedDeeper": [
      {
        "keepsNesting": [
          {
            "otherKey": "7890"
          }
        ],
        "hereToo": {
          "goodishKey": "baz"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a nice pythonic way to do this?  Also, the input and output should be a byte string like the following (spaces don't matter to me as long as json is ok with them):

```
b'{"badKey": "0001","goodKey": "5432","interestingList": [{"badKey": "0001", "goodKey": "0101" }],"coolList": {"nestedDeeper": [{"keepsNesting": [{"badKey": "9999", "otherKey": "7890" }], "hereToo": {"badKey": "foobar", "goodishKey": "baz"}}]}}'
```

I'm sure I could come up with some regex to search/replace the data in the input string, but I think it would be difficult to ensure the json syntax was left intact through it all, so I'm thinking to load it into the json module and manipulate it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is recursively traverse the data and remove the key if found:

```
import json


json_string = b'{"badKey": "0001","goodKey": "5432","interestingList": [{"badKey": "0001", "goodKey": "0101" }],"coolList": {"nestedDeeper": [{"keepsNesting": [{"badKey": "9999", "otherKey": "7890" }], "hereToo": {"badKey": "foobar", "goodishKey": "baz"}}]}}'

def remove_key(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if 'badKey' in d:
            del d['badKey']
        for v in d.values():
            remove_key(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            remove_key(v)

data = json.loads(json_string.decode('utf-8'))
remove_key(data)
# pretty print on screen:
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
# ...or convert to bytes:
print(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "goodKey": "5432",
    "interestingList": [
        {
            "goodKey": "0101"
        }
    ],
    "coolList": {
        "nestedDeeper": [
            {
                "keepsNesting": [
                    {
                        "otherKey": "7890"
                    }
                ],
                "hereToo": {
                    "goodishKey": "baz"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And byte representation:

```
b'{"goodKey": "5432", "interestingList": [{"goodKey": "0101"}], "coolList": {"nestedDeeper": [{"keepsNesting": [{"otherKey": "7890"}], "hereToo": {"goodishKey": "baz"}}]}}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just recurse through the loaded dictionary:

```py
def deleteBadKey(badKey, dictionary):
    for k, v in list(dictionary.items()):
        if k == badKey:
            del dictionary[k]
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            deleteBadKey(badKey, v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                deleteBadKey(badKey, d)
```